# JavaScript cant get element from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I can't use the html elment with the id

> notification-panel-sidebar

in my JavaScript, but I can Access it directly using jquery.

This is the Code:

```
const notificationContainer = {

    elements: {
        notificationPanelSidebar: $('#notification-panel-sidebar'),
        notificationPanelSidebarContainer: $('#notification-panel-sidebar-container')
    },

    classes: {
        notificationContainerActive: 'notification-container-active'
    },

    render () {
        this.toggleNotificationContainer();
    },

    toggleNotificationContainer () {
        console.log(this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar);
        this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar.click((e) => { // this does not work
        // $('#notification-panel-sidebar').click((e) => { // this works
            let _this = $(e.currentTarget);
            if (_this.hasClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive)) {
                console.log("+++++++");
                this.hideNotificationContainer();
            } else {
                console.log("-------");
                _this.addClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive);
                this.elements.notificationPanelSidebarContainer.show();
            }
        });
    },

    hideNotificationContainer () {
        this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar.removeClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive);
        this.elements.notificationPanelSidebarContainer.hide();
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    notificationContainer.render();
});
```

I get no error message.

Comment: Problem is `this` reference not pointing to the DOM element itself, instead it points to the jQuery object. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) question for more info about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) reference in javascript

Comment: @Anddo He's using an arrow function, so it refers to the `notificationContainer` object.

Comment: That's right I didn't pay attention to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the `notificationContainer` object before the DOM is ready, so `$('#notification-panel-sidebar')` doesn't select anything. Put the variable initialization inside `$(document).ready()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const notificationContainer = {

    elements: {
      notificationPanelSidebar: $('#notification-panel-sidebar'),
      notificationPanelSidebarContainer: $('#notification-panel-sidebar-container')
    },

    classes: {
      notificationContainerActive: 'notification-container-active'
    },

    render() {
      this.toggleNotificationContainer();
    },

    toggleNotificationContainer() {
      console.log(this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar);
      this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar.click((e) => { // this does not work
        // $('#notification-panel-sidebar').click((e) => { // this works
        let _this = $(e.currentTarget);
        if (_this.hasClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive)) {
          console.log("+++++++");
          this.hideNotificationContainer();
        } else {
          console.log("-------");
          _this.addClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive);
          this.elements.notificationPanelSidebarContainer.show();
        }
      });
    },

    hideNotificationContainer() {
      this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar.removeClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive);
      this.elements.notificationPanelSidebarContainer.hide();
    }

  }
  notificationContainer.render();
});
```

Comment: I thought my last 3 lines do the magic, so you say I run this `$(document).ready()` before the const declaration

Comment: The last 3 lines call `render` after the document is ready, but the problem is with the initialization of the `elements` element.

Comment: ok thanks it worked, I am requiring some js files in my app.js how would you use `$(document).ready()` in all of them without repeating it in every single file `require('./bootstrap');
require('./notificationContainer');
require('./navbar');
require('./urlPathChecker');`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, I haven't used the module stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work?

```js
const notificationContainer = {

    elements: {
        notificationPanelSidebar: $('#notification-panel-sidebar'),
        notificationPanelSidebarContainer: $('#notification-panel-sidebar-container')
    },

    classes: {
        notificationContainerActive: 'notification-container-active'
    },

    render () {
        this.toggleNotificationContainer();
    },

    toggleNotificationContainer () {
        console.log(this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar);
        this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar.click((e) => { // this does not work
        // $('#notification-panel-sidebar').click((e) => { // this works
            let _this = $(e.currentTarget);
            if (_this.hasClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive)) {
                console.log("+++++++");
                this.hideNotificationContainer();
            } else {
                console.log("-------");
                _this.addClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive);
                this.elements.notificationPanelSidebarContainer.show();
            }
        });
    },

    hideNotificationContainer () {
        this.elements.notificationPanelSidebar.removeClass(this.classes.notificationContainerActive);
        this.elements.notificationPanelSidebarContainer.hide();
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    notificationContainer.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification-panel-sidebar">
sidebar
</div>
<div id="notification-panel-sidebar-container">
sidebar-container
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Snippet puts the Javascript at the bottom of the HTML, so the DOM elements exist when the JS runs.